# Set Nimbus Look and Feel Java Tutorials - will never get to the catch block to set another look and feel

Tags: java, look-and-feel

The Java Tutorials gives the following example for setting the Nimbus Look and Feel:  [The Java Tutorials - Nimbus Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)

```
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;

try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```

It seems to me the catch would only occur if the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` throws an exception.
If you put code to set another look and feel in the catch block, it should theoretically never execute since you are only using the `.setLookAndFeel()` on installed `LookAndFeel`s.
If Nimbus is not available on the system, it will fall through the ForEach and out the try-catch block, not having set anything.

Shouldn't the code for "If nimbus is not available..." go after the ForEach and before the catch?
In the catch block you might want to specify the SystemLookAndFeel or DefaultLookAndFeel supplied with JAVA.

Am I correct about the try-catch block as stated above? I'm concerned I'm missing something since this example code has been quoted many times and I've seen this question raised.

Answer (score 0):

Nimbus is always available from the class level, as it is included in every JRE after Java 1.5.

What it is meant by "Not Available" is possibly if the system fails to load the object, by any problem in the reflect mechanism.

In any case, I'd say you should set the other Look-and-Feel in a `finally` block. This way it you can load alternatives even in lower versions of Java.